# node.js express e-commerce number of views

Tags: node.js, e-commerce

I'm working on an e-commerce website project. I want to count views on each product and display on the single product display page. I know it can be easily implemented by adding a count into express routes and then load into database.
But it will be a burden for the DB connection if for each view I need to connect to the DB and increment the index.

I have a second solution but not sure if it is a better solution since I didn't have any experience on these fields.
The solution is : use a variable to count number of views for each item, and send a query every day to record this variable, or load into a json file every X (minutes/hours..)

What is the best way to count these stuff without sacrificing the performance of the website?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the counter against each endpoint in a Redis server. It's in-memory so read/writes are fast. And you can persist it to disk too.

Check out this [redis client for Node.js](https://github.com/luin/ioredis).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Redis is awesome! do you know where is redis installed? Does in-memory mean that it is not installed on the hard drive?

Comment: Where it is installed is a different topic. The relevant part for us is that data that you write to a redis server is held in-memory.. So if you dont set it up in a way that it persist to memory in set intervals, everything you store will be lost if youre redis server goes down.

Comment: I see. Than you so much!